# Change subdomain root with htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My webhost allows me to create subdomains, but not to change the root folder that those subdomains point to (which make them kind of useless for my needs). I'm wondering if it's possible to use htaccess and mod_rewrite to mimic the behaviour of a different subdomain root.

So, I would like requests to mysite.com to map to /wwwroot/mysite.com/index.html, and requests to dev.mysite.com to would map to /wwwroot/mysite.com/dev.mysite.com/index.html.

Ideally, this would be done without triggering an http redirect.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Do you also intend to block direct access to `/dev.mysite.com/index.html`?

Comment: Michael, that's not really necessary in this case, but feel free to post a method for doing so for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^dev\.mysite\.com /dev.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```